# How would I use the properties of the Riemann integral to prove this?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> $$\left|\int_0^{2\pi} x^2\sin^8(e^x) \ dx\right| \le  \frac{8π^3}3$$

Hi, I know you have to use the properties of Riemann integrals but I don't know how to apply them to this question. 
I know I have to use

$$\int_0^b x^2 \ dx = \frac{b^3}{3} $$

Comment: You can use the fact that $|\sin^8(e^x)| \le 1$ and $|\int f(x)\ dx| \le \int |f(x)| dx$

Answer (score 2):

By the triangle inequality and the trivial bound on $\sin$, 
$$
\left |\int_0^{2\pi}x^2\sin(e^x)\,\mathrm dx\right | \leq 
\int_0^{2\pi} \left |x^2\sin(e^x) \, \mathrm dx\right |\\
\stackrel{|\sin y|\leq 1|}{\leq }\int_0^{2\pi}x^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac{(2\pi)^3}{3}
$$

Comment: ahh thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \left|\int_0^{2\pi} x^2\sin^8(e^x) \ dx\right| \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^{2\pi} x^2 \sin^8(e^x) \, dx & & \text{because the function is everywhere nonnegative} \\[10pt]
\le {} & \int_0^{2\pi} x^2 \, dx & & \text{because the values of the sine function are }\le 1 \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{8\pi^3} 3.
\end{align}